# Does HTTPS connection disabled jQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, https

I have the following php script which works flawlessly in normal circumstances (i.e. visiting the page directly):

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/contact_search.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.watermarkinput.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$(document).click(function() {
    $("#display").hide();
});

var cache = {};

    $("#searchbox").keyup(function() {
        var searchbox = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 'searchword=' + searchbox;

        if (searchbox.length < 3 ) {
            $("#display").hide();
            } else {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "contact_search/search.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {

                    $("#display").html(html).show();
                }
            });
        return false;
    });
});

jQuery(function($) {
    $("#searchbox").Watermark("Search for Group");
});
</script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#e0e0e0">
<div class="body">


          <div class="liquid-round" style="width:100%;">
            <div class="top"><span><h2>Contacts List</h2></span></div>

            <div class="center-content"> 
                <img src="images/search.gif" style="float:right;" />
                <input type="text" id="searchbox" maxlength="20" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['hello'];?>" />
                <div id="display"></div><div style="clear:both;"></div>

            </div>

            <div class="bottom"><span></span></div>
        </div>


        <div class="liquid-round" style="width:97%;">
            <div class="top"><span><h2>My Messages</h2></span></div>

            <div class="center-content" style="min-height:200px;">                        
            </div>

            <div class="bottom"><span></span></div>
        </div>    


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

HOWEVER - when I add the following piece to the top of the page, the javascript/jquery functions simply stop working altogether.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if( $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 80) {
        header('Location:https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); 
        die();
    }
?>
```

These pages require login so I need to ensure they are https protected but this error messes all that up. Any ideas what could be causing the issue?

Comment: Is there any javascript errors? Also you should have a local copy of jQuery or change the http to https so that you don't get any of the security errors about it being on a non secure site.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's probably the browser not displaying insecure (http) content on https pages, there's a simple fix though, use a scheme relative URL, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This way you'll get `http://ajax.googleapis.com/....` on the `http://` version of your page and  `https://ajax.googleapis.com/....` on the `https://` version.

Comment: Wow, how did I not know about this? Is this supported by all browsers?

Comment: @Nick - is it possible to "share" a the jquery src link above on one page with 4 frames (in a frameset) as opposed to having to call it on each page (i realize the actual functions need to be called but trying to minimize calls to the same google cdn)

Comment: @JM4 - nope...but the browser should fetch it once, use the cached version for the other 4 frames (on the first load), then use the cached version for all frames for any load after that.

Comment: woah woah woah..... scheme relative URLs!?!? and this has existed for years? this needs to be publicized more!

Answer (score 0):

Since session_start produces HTTP-Headers I recommend to do the port check before session_start.

But, these lines should not affect your JS in any circumstances, because the redirect to HTTPS is independend from the fact if your site is working via HTTPS. So, if you are not sure, remove the lines and access your page with HTTPS. Bring JS to work there. And afterwards implement the redirect.